# can I cut in / blend old brick extension

Tags: walls, exterior, brick

Our house was extended some time before we moved in and it has left a straight line of mortar running down the front and back of the building went instead of cutting out the half bricks that wrap around they have just fixed cut bricks.

I'm assuming this was just a lazy developer rushing the job..

It's it possible for me to work my way up and cut out every other brick and fit a new to join the two buildings back together?

The brick work all lines up correctly between old and new so the replacements should be perfect.

If I'm mistaken and this is actually standard practice could I perhaps cut out around a third of the half bricks depth and re-face them with a slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can cut out and bond in new bricks to get a seamless match in the bond (assuming the gap is not an expansion joint - if it's mortar-pointed it's unlikely to be; an expansion joint should have sealant in it).

The main issue that you will run into is likely to be the ties used to fix the new wall to the old. If wall starters were used, they'll run right the way up the height of the wall in the joint and be in the way of where you are looking to put the new bricks. As you are bonding it with new brick, you won't need to worry about replacing any ties you have to take out.

Re-facing the bricks will be a hell of a job - the bricks will be hard and it won't be easy to tacke the face off in situ. Plus you'll need a diamond saw to cut faces off the new bricks (or to buy slip bricks from a merchant - most will be able to get these to order). My biggest concern with that would be ensuring that they are suitably bonded so that the faces don't blow off with freeze-thaw.

Comment: Thanks for this john. Very helpful. I'm sure it's not anexpansion joint as you say there is no sealant. I'll go for the cutting out and bonding then and hope for the best re the ties. A little more work but worth it I think. Any advice on technique for bonding new bricks in?

Comment: Make sure you clean off all the old mortar and that each new brick gets a good bed of mortar to site on. The hardest part will be ensureing that you get the perpend and top joints fully packed with mortar. Have you found matching bricks?